# Click even not working on <Label> [ Using EasyUI ]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-easyui

In my project,I am using EasyUI.
I have two labels 'AA' and 'BB' whose color changes when I hover over it.Now,I want to do something when Label is clicked.But the click event is not working.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    function recDoc(){
    alert("xietst");
    }
</script>
<body style="height:100%">
    <style>
        .dlgLabel{cursor:pointer}
        .dlgLabel:hover {background-color:blue;color:white}
    </style>
    <div  id="dlg" class="easyui-dialog"  title="" 
style="width:88px;height:260px;top:130px;left:170px;padding:10px">
        <label class="dlgLabel" onclick="recDoc()">AA</label><br />
        <label class="dlgLabel">BB</label><br />
    </div>
</body>
```

When I delete the `class=easyui-dialog`,it works.

But I would like for the label to be clickable even when I use easyui. Any help would be great.

Comment: Your onclick is working as expected when clicked on AA label. BB label has onclick event missing so it does not work when clicked

Comment: I have tested that Clicked on AA label does not work

Comment: Have you prevented the page from opening additional dialogs? Try in some different browser

Comment: I have tested firfox, chrome and IE, They all work fail

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the example as it is on the docs:

http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=Dialog